How to conduct error analysis for gradient descent with a function not differentiable everywhere
I am trying to bound the error of a method which uses gradient descent on a function which has the term $\lVert Ax - b \rVert$. The analytical solution of the derivative of $\lVert Ax - b \rVert$ is $\frac{A^{\top}(Ax-b)}{\lVert Ax - b \rVert}$, so the function is not differentiable when $Ax = b$ due to division by zero. Because of this, I am unable to use Lipschitz continuity arguments. What are some ways I can work around this issue?
Some of the approaches I have thought about:

Using subdifferentials. This does not seem applicable here because, although the subdifferential does exist at $Ax = b$ and is the unit ball, it still does not address what happens when the subderivative $= 0$.
Adding an infinitesimally small term (e.g. 1e-10) to the denominator of $\frac{A^{\top}(Ax-b)}{\lVert Ax - b \rVert}$ when carrying out the gradient steps computationally. However, I'm not sure how I would justify this mathematically.
Bounding the domain of the norm so that it approaches, but never reaches, $0$. This translates to me having to justify why $Ax$ never approaches $b$ in practice.
Somehow using a smoothed version of $\frac{A^{\top}(Ax-b)}{\lVert Ax - b \rVert}$, which will be Lipschitz continuous. However, this will introduce a smoothing error.

None of these options seem to be ideal, so I was wondering whether any of them should actually be used and if there exist other, better, alternatives.
Edit: The context for this problem is that it is an online optimization problem connected to an "external system"; at every iteration, an input $x_k$ is fed into a (fixed) linear system to give $Ax_k$, which is supposed to track a reference value $b$, which may or may not be time-varying. To determine $x_{k+1}$, a gradient step is then taken where ${\lVert Ax - b \rVert}$ is one of the terms in the objective function.

Your third solution is by far the best one. You don’t have to justify why $Ax$ doesn’t approach $b$, only that it doesn’t exactly equal $b$, which in practice is very rare and is often ignored. Further context may be helpful to provide a better answer.

I see, thank you. In the context I provided, I was thinking that perhaps one possible condition to ensure $Ax \neq b$ is to have the linear system $Ax = b$ be overdetermined. Not looking at the context, is that assumption ever mathematically acceptable?

Yes, that seems like a valid solution. I would however like to emphasize that I’ve seen many examples of algorithms where division by $0$ is ignored for simplicity. Note that in this case the derivative does not grow arbitrarily large near the discontinuity, so the problems it poses are limited.

@beanbanx: Your first claim that the subdifferential does not exist at $Ax = b$ is not correct - the subdifferential of the $\ell_2$ norm at 0 is nonempty and equal to the unit ball.

That's true; I've realized that as well. Thank you for pointing it out.
